# Find the surface of that part of $x^2+y^2=2az, (a>0)$ that's inside the cylinder $(x^2+y^2)^2=a^2(x^2-y^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

My attempt:

After transforming $(x^2+y^2)^2 = a^2(x^2-y^2)$ using polar coordinates, we get that one 'loop' of this special cylinder is given for $-\pi/4 \le \theta \le \pi/4$ and for $0 \le r \le a\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$.

So a good parameterization would be $\phi(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,\frac{r^2}{2a})$, with the restrictions on $\theta, r$ as mentioned prior.

Then $\left\| \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \times\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta}\right\|= \frac{r}a \sqrt{r^2+a^2}.$ Eventually we get:

$$ S(\Sigma)= 2 \cdot \frac1a \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}d\theta\int_0^{a\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}}r\sqrt{r^2+a^2}dr.$$

This gives the following integral: $$ \frac{2a^2}3\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}((\cos(2\theta)+1)^{3/2}-1)d\theta.$$

I had no idea how to solve this, so I used Wolfram Alpha to calculate this integral. I got $-0.875806i$, which seems very odd.

The answer to this problem should be $\frac{a^2}9(20-3\pi)$. Is my set up incorrect? Or maybe my parameterization?

Thanks.

Comment: Since *Mathematica* comes up with the answer you are looking for, I would guess your integral is correct.  How did you code this in Alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle I= \frac{2}{3} a^2 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \left( (\cos 2\theta + 1)^{3/2} - 1\right) \, d\theta$

The identity: $\cos 2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta$ lets us write the integral as

$$I = \frac{2}{3} a^2  \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}  (2^{3/2} \cos^3 \theta  -1 ) \, d\theta$$

Since $$\displaystyle \cos ^3\theta = \frac{3 \cos \theta}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \cos 3\theta, $$ we can write

$$I = \frac{2}{3} a^2 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}  \left( \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\theta + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos 3\theta -1 \right) \, d\theta $$

or

$$I =  a^2 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}  \left( {\sqrt{2}} \cos\theta + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \cos 3\theta -\frac{2}{3} \right) \, d\theta $$

$$I = \left(2 + \frac{2}{9} - \frac{\pi}{3}\right) a^2 = \left( \frac{20}{9}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)a^2$$

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* gives the correct answer:

```
2/3 a^2 Integrate[(Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 1)^(3/2) - 1, {\[Theta], -\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4}]
```

Result:

$\displaystyle \frac{a^2}{9} (20 - 3 \pi)$

Comment: I tried again and now I find the answer I was looking for. Maybe a typo? Do you have any ideas on how to solve this integral algebraically?

Comment: Yes.  I posted it as another answer (since it may not fit here in the comments).